# Reliability of a loop of seven bulbs that will stay on as long as no two adjacent lamps fail

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, reliability

I'm an engineer and I know probability and combinatorics reasonably well, but this problem has me stumped.

I have tried approaching the problem as a 7-bit binary string, then joining the ends to make a loop.

I've seen a solution that considers the general case of $n$ bulbs. It begins by snipping the loop into a string and computing the number of $k$-bulb failures. It sets up this recurrence, which seems incorrect to me:

${n \choose k}$ =  ${n-2 \choose k-1}$ +  ${n-1 \choose k}$

I know that this holds: ${n \choose k}$ =  ${n-1 \choose k-1}$ +  ${n-1 \choose k}$.

That's where I get stumped and can't continue.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: This needs more details. How do you define reliability and what is the probability that an individual bulb will fail?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the recurrence relation is incorrect?

Comment: @JohnDouma, each bulb fails with a probability of $q$. Failures are independent.

Comment: @cpiegore, I think the first recurrence is incorrect because I know the second one is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I will offer a very simple (i.e. inelegant) solution that does **not** generalize well, but that is easy to understand, for the specific case of $7$ lamps, looped together.

For simplicity, I am assuming that the probability that a specific lamp is good is $p$, that the probability that a specific lamp is bad is $q = (1 - p)$, that the $p,q$ constants apply to each of the lamps, and that the probability of any lamp being good is independent of any other lamp being good.

In effect, you have the lamps *seated at a round table* in positions 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, where 7 is right next to 1.  My approach to exploring having no consecutive bad lamps will be to examine the mutually exclusive cases of $0$ bad lamps, $1$ bad lamp, $2$ bad lamps, or $3$ bad lamps.

Note that $4$ or more bad lamps can be rejected, since this would compel two consecutive bad lamps.

I will let the partial sums be denoted as $~P_k ~: ~k \in \{0,1,2,3\}$, where $P_k$ is the partial sum under the assumption that $k$ of the lamps are bad.

Clearly, if $k=0$, you are automatically satisfied, so

$$P_0 = p^7.$$

Similarly, if $k = 1,$ you also can't have consecutive bad lamps.  So,

$$P_1 = \binom{7}{1}p^6q = 7p^6q.$$

For $k=2$, things get complicated.  If you select any two lamps, arbitrarily, you are looking at a probability of $p^5q^2.$  The issue is, how many of the $~\displaystyle\binom{7}{2} = 21~$ ways of selecting the two bad lamps are **unsatisfying**.  Answer: $(7)$ :

$(1,2), (2,3), \cdots, (6,7), (7,1)$.

Therefore,

$$P_2 = \left[\binom{7}{2} - 7\right] p^5q^2 = 14p^5q^2.$$

---

The enumeration of $P_3$ is similar.  If you have $(3)$ bad lamps, out of the $~\displaystyle \binom{7}{3} = 35~$ ways of selecting the bad lamps, the only satisfying ways of selecting them are

$(1,3,5), (1,3,6), (1,4,6), (2,4,6), (2,4,7), (2,5,7), (3,5,7).$

Therefore,

$$P_3 = 7 p^4q^3.$$

---

Putting this all together,

the overall probability of having satisfying lamps is

$$P_0 + P_1 + P_2 + P_3$$

$$= p^7 + 7p^6q + 14p^5q^2 + 7p^4q^3.$$

---

Note that I gave a very inelegant analysis that does **not** generalize well.  This is the specific answer to the specific posted question.  If you (the OP - i.e. original poster) need a more elegant approach that generalizes well, leave a comment, following my answer, and I will provide a (complicated) general approach.

Taking your posting at face value, the answer given is a good answer to provide to an Engineer, rather than to a Mathematician.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution is as follows. Let $P_L(n)$ be the probability of failure in a loop of $n$ bulbs and $P_S(n)$ the probability of failure in a string of $n$ bulbs. Then $$P_L(n)=pP_S(n-1)\mbox{  [bulb 1 survives]}$$ $$+qp^2P_S(n-3) \mbox{  [bulb 1 fails but bulbs 2 and n survive]}$$ $$+q(1-p^2) \mbox{  [bulb 1 and at least one of 2 and n fail]}.$$ and $$P_S(n)=q^2 \mbox{  [bulbs 1 and 2 fail]}$$ $$+pP_S(n-1) \mbox{  [bulb 1 survives]}$$ $$+qpP_S(n-2) \mbox{  [bulb 1 fails but bulb 2 survives]}.$$ This reproduces the solution of @user2661923 for $n=7$.

$P_S(1)=0$ and $P_S(2)=q^2$, so $P_S(3)=q^2(1+p)$, $P_S(4)=q^2(1+2p)$, $P_S(5)=q^2(1+2p+2p^2-p^3)$,$P_S(6)=q^2(1+2p+3p^2-p^4)$ so $$P_L(7)=q^2(1+2p+3p^2+4p^3-2p^4-p^5)=1-p^4[p^3-7p+7]$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability of having no bulb fail is $p^7$.  Otherwise (if there is at least one failed bulb), the number of ways to select $r > 0$ out of $n$ objects in a circular arrangement with no two adjacent is
$$\frac{n}{r}\binom{n-r-1}{r-1} \tag{*}$$
So the probability that $7$ bulbs arranged in a circle will have no two adjacent bulbs fail is
$$p^7 + \sum_{r=1}^3 \frac{7}{r}\binom{7-r-1}{r-1} q^r p^{7-r}$$
where the probability that a bulb fails is $q$, and $p=1-q$.

To show $(*)$, we first consider the number of ways to select integers $a_1, a_2, \dots ,a_r$ from the set $\{1,2, \dots ,n\}$ with no two adjacent. For the choices to be non-adjacent, we must have $1 \le a_1$, $a_1 < a_2-1$, $a_2 < a_3-1$, $a_3 < a_4-1$, ..., $a_{r-1} < a_r -1$, and $a_r \le n$.  An equivalent set of inequalities is
$$1 \le a_1 < a_2-1 < a_3-2 < a_4-3 < \dots < a_r-r+1 \le n-r+1$$
So we may equivalently pick the values $ a_1 , a_2-1 , a_3-2 , a_4-3 , \dots , a_r-r+1$ from $\{1, 2, 3, \dots ,n-r+1 \}$, and this can be done in $\binom{n-r+1}{r}$ ways.

Now suppose we make selections from a circular arrangement of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ with no two selections adjacent; this differs from a linear arrangement only in that we may not select both $1$ and $n$.  So how many arrangements does this eliminate?  If a selection is bad in the sense that both $1$ and $n$ are selected but otherwise acceptable, then it must also be that neither $2$ nor $n-1$ is selected.  We are left with $r-2$ non-adjacent integers to select from the $n-4$ integers from $3$ to $n-2$, and we know from above that this can be done in $\binom{(n-4)-(r-2)+1}{r-2}$ ways. So the number of ways to select $r$ integers from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ with no two adjacent in the circular sense is
$$\binom{n-r+1}{r}-\binom{(n-4)-(r-2)+1}{r-2} = \frac{n}{r}\binom{n-r-1}{r-1}$$